# Проблема при генерации кода в idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Я создаю форму, и прошу среду intllij idea сгенерировать код для создания формы в класс, однако в этом коде появляются ссылки на объекты, которых нет в моем проекте (например: `com.intellij.*`) в проекте нет этого расположения. Как решить эту проблему?

UPD: При инициализации этой формы `main wind = new main();` выполняется код ниже, но при этом не появляется форма.

```
public main() {
    $$$setupUI$$$();
    panel1.setVisible(true);
    startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            textField1.setText("text");
        }
    });
}
```

UPD: Решил проблему необходимо унаследовать класс формы от JFrame `public class main extends JFrame {` и кодом ниже вывести эту форму

```
setContentPane(panel1);
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
pack();
setVisible(true);
```

где `panel1` это панель с элементами управления

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если вы делаете плагин для идеи, то настройте SDK проекта (File->Project structure->Project), создайте и выберите IntelliJ platform SDK.

Если что-то другое, добавьте нужный .jar как external library.

Project Structure->Modules->Dependencies
Add... → Project Library → Attach Jar

Comment: а почему не возникает форма при исполнении метода main?

Comment: @max619 Не изменяйте существующий, а создайте новый вопрос